# A word for the text between section heading (e.g., Section 1) and first subsection heading (e.g., Section 1.1)

Tags: word-choice

What are possible words (or ideally a specific professional term) for the text between a section heading and the first corresponding subsection heading (in the text body, not the table of contents).

I have found "preamble", but, since preamble certainly is used to refer to an introductionary text for the whole document (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preamble), think that there might be a more specific professional term for it.

> **1 Introduction**
>
> *Here is the running text of the introduction for which I would like to have a word*
>
> **1.1 Motivation**
>
> **1.2 Objectives**

Comment: If you don't like the reasonable choice of "preamble", have you looked for its synonyms?

Comment: I don't think that preamble is a reasonable choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preamble

Comment: Wikipedia is not the only source of authority. First look at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/preamble: "an introduction to a speech or piece of writing". A piece of writing does not necessarily mean *all* the writing. Or look at Merriam Webster. "Preamble" is a good place to start a relevant synonym search, which is what you should have done before asking a question that is clearly based on your understanding of the word.

Comment: Choosing to use a highly structured format - 1 / 1.1 / 1.2.1 *etc* - and then inserting freeform, floating 'comments' is confusing.  What is the point of sections and subsections if you are going to add bits between them occasionally?  Why not put your explanatory comment at the start of the section it refers to?  Perhaps even make it the title of the section...

Comment: Exactly my opinion, @Dan. However, there is a large fraction (in academia), which not only does not share your oppinion but even enforces this "floating" text, as you described (maybe for lacking of a better term). So I want to know how that is called so I can form a better understanding and convince my students not only based on personal preference.

Comment: @Anton I could also call it Introduction or one of the many „synonyms“ for preamble. This is not the point. What you don’t seem to understand is that I am hoping that there exists a specific professional term for exactly what I described. Three options: 1. you know the term (and tell me), 2. you know that this term does not exist, or 3. you tell my why you think that then the question is a „learners question“, which is kinda ironic if 1.and 2 don’t apply. You could also call widows and orphans „sentences“, but then again, you missed the point https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans

Comment: If you have a style guide that tells you to include this text, doesn't the style guide give it a name?

Comment: @StuartF No, they paraphrase it, e.g., "Between a chapter title and its first subsection, there should be an overview describing what the chapter is about and how it is organized." (https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/crea-lit/headings-and-subheadings). Also nice examples are https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/put-text-between-section-and-subsection-headings or https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72124/bad-style-to-start-text-in-subsection

Comment: @Anton And do you even know yourself what you meant with: "before asking a question that is clearly based on your understanding of the word."? How is this question based on my understanding of the word preamble?

Comment: I found the question on academia, where it has 7 upvotes (somehow noone thought it should be migrated to english learner's) https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162433/what-is-the-name-of-the-text-that-might-exist-after-the-chapter-heading-and-befo

Comment: An astonishing comment from you. There four reasons to suppose you understand something about "preamble": your question mentions "preamble"; it references a source of meaning of "preamble";  it gives your opinion about "preamble"; and it asks for something beyond "preamble".  Are these points not sufficient to suppose you know something about the word and could have set out the reasons for not wanting to use it?

Comment: It is not based on my understanding of the word preamble (whatever that’s supposed to mean) but is based on the desire to find a word (the Word, preferably) for something that may be described as „chapter abstract“. Preamble is not a great choice, and definitely not a specific term having that meaning. you asked me why think preamble is not a good choice and I thought that my edit and Wikipedia citation shows you why, because it’s pretty obvious. In turn you immediately resorted to pseudo intellectual arrogance even though you have exactly zero to contribute to my question.

Comment: @Dan I don’t think the text is “floating” or unclear; in fact I prefer that style as I hate to start reading a section and have no info what is coming up except from the TOC. The section intro is associated with all of section #1, and acts as a summary or introduction. Once the section 1 subsections start, it’s not possible to have more text for whole of section #1. PS. I’m not sure what its official name is! PPS. Can’t understand why this was migrated from ELU to ELL.

Comment: @k1eran - one of my suggestions was that explanatory floating text can be formulated as a title for each section/subsection - *2. Widgets and tidbits ... 2.1  Review of previous widget and tidbit studies ... 2.2  Rationale for choosing widgets in this study ... etc*

Comment: @Dan While I appreciate your remarks even though the question was not about whether there should be a chapter abstract: Please do without the dot for the first level heading — it’s not „Chapter Second Widgets and tidbits“ ;)

Comment: @k1eran, was there a logical reason to migrate? Certainly not. I think you can see from the discussion with one of the migrators (@Anton) that „power“ doesn’t need reason or even worse. This is actually the perfect question for ELU since there seems to be no „official“ term.

Comment: I am having **real trouble with this question**. In an outline, you have headings, sub-headings, and sub-sub-headings.  There is nothing else. If your text comes any heading, it is **just text**. What else could it be? And in legal texts, a preamble is actually the name of a heading and a type of text.

Comment: https://open.lib.umn.edu/publicspeaking/chapter/12-2-types-of-outlines/

Comment: @Lambie I guess what you describe as "text" refers to paragraphs. Paragraphs are what you place inside (sub-)chapters, sections etc. (whatever term you choose) with the difference that they are not numbered. Paragraphs in turn contain sentences. Sentences contain words. Words contain letters. I don't see why you have trouble with the question, though. My question is not about the word preamble. My question is about paragraphs, which are placed outside of subchapters of a specific chapter. Please specify what you mean.

Comment: @SebastianE I have been working with outlines for 30 years. Generally speaking, there are the words in the outline that come after the numbering of the outline regardless of how you number them or use letters to describe them. Those levels of an outline contain words, i.e. text. **Generally** in an outline of whatever type, there are no "words **between** a section heading and a subsection. All words in an outline go right after the letter or number referring to it. Not floating in white space beneath it.

Comment: @lambie are you using “outline” to refer to the table of contents?

Comment: Of course, I am. Tables of content are a kind of outline of a paper.

Comment: Well, my question is not about the ToC, but the body; I have made an edit.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about what to call a block of text that appears in the space between a section heading and the first in a series of subordinate section subheads. At the various publishing houses where I have worked, the term I have used (and heard used) for such text is "**section intro**"; if there is a single word for it, I've never heard it.

The rationale for calling it a "section intro" is that it is only a small part of the full section that it introduces. The full section comprises the main section heading (in your example, "1 Introduction"), the section intro text, all of the hierarchically subordinate subheads (in your example, "1.1 Motivation" and "1.2 Objectives"), and all running text that appears beneath each subhead. The signal to readers that they have reached the end of a full section (that is, the section intro plus all subsections (including subheads) is the appearance of the next section heading (e.g., "2 Making Sense of Section Intros").

Section intro text is an extremely common element in publishing because many publishers require that there be at least some running text between any section heading or subhead and a following subordinate subhead or sub-subhead. This is not a universal rule, however. *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2919), for example, states, at **1.54** (***Subhead levels and placement***), "A lower-level subhead may follow an upper-level subhead with no intervening text." Still, in my experience, many publishing houses frequently break with *Chicago* on this point.

Answer (score -4):

In HTML, one could call it a "header":

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p> … </p>
    </header>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2>1. Subtitle</h2>
            <p> … </p>
        </header>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>1.1 Subtitle</h3>
                <p> … </p>
            </header>
            <p> … </p>
            …
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>1.2 Subtitle</h3>
                <p> … </p>
            </header>
            <p> … </p>
            <p> … </p>
            …
        </section>
        …
    </section>
    …
    <footer>
        <p> … </p>
    </footer>
</article>
```